# Laravel 5 on php artisan config:clear generated Closure::__set_state() error

Tags: php, laravel-5

My code in on production and I ran

```
php artisan config:clear
```

After that, my code was not running. The index pages and all other pages went white screen and gave 500 internal server error in firebug. When I tried to run

```
php artisan
```

it gave me error as

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Closure::__set_state() in /var/www/live/vendor/config.php on line 56
```

My code is in production!! /vendor/config.php file was not present before, what happened with that code??
Have you faced any such error?
I had given all permissions to storage/ folder and vendor/.
Any help/guide would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had faced the similar issue in past don't know what caused it but as of now you can delete the `config.php` from `/vendor` it won't break your code.

And your code will be start working..

Comment: This solution is just for one time, when you run the code `php artisan config:cache` the 2nd time it will pop up the error again

Answer (score 31):

I had similar issues when I ran `php artisan config:cache`. Apparently, it is an issue when the application is trying to load cached configuration files that have closures in it. It won't be fixed in Laravel since it is a bad practice to have closures in config files. Refer this Github [issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9625)

The way I solved this is by undo-ing this.

Delete the cache for config.

It is located in here

`bootstrap/cache/config.php`

OR

`vendor/config.php`

Comment: I'm not sure that this adds anything to the Answer that I posted two weeks earlier (but maybe I'm wrong, given the upvotes). Just sayin'. :)

Comment: [@Ben Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1772379/ben-johnson) Honestly, I think his answer was formatted so you could get to the solution faster. I am upvoting your answer too because you put in a little more effort :-)

Answer (score 8):

Among other root-causes, this error results from calling `php artisan config:cache` when a closure is defined inside any configuration file that Laravel attempts to load. Laravel does not allow for closures in configuration files; see:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9625

Deleting the resultant cache file, usually located at `bootstrap/cache/config.php`, "fixes" the error.

The long-term solution is to eliminate closures from all configuration files. The problematic config file can be determined by inspecting the offending line, as mentioned in the error message.

If the offending file is third-party, it is best to open an issue with the library, so that the issue is fixed upstream.

Answer (score 7):

Here is what I did to solve it:

1. Go to /vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/config/config.php and replace the lines for `storage` and `auth` with:

`'auth' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\Auth\IlluminateAuthAdapter',

'storage' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\Storage\IlluminateCacheAdapter'`

2. Go to `/bootstrap/cache/config.php` and delete it
3. Run the following commands in order:
   A) `php artisan config/cache`
   B) `php artisan jwt:generate`
   C) `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider"`

and that should do it!

Answer (score 4):

Try to remove the config.php from `bootstrap/cache` folder. It worked for me.

Comment: Super helpful! Thanks. I ran `mv bootstrap/cache/config.php bootstrap/cache/config_old.php` and then `php artisan config:clear`

Answer (score 0):

Edit `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php:108`
and delete required.

Answer (score -1):

Changing the `config.php` file inside the `vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/config` to this

```
'auth' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\Auth\IlluminateAuthAdapter::class`
```

and this

```
'storage' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\Storage\IlluminateCacheAdapter::class`
```

before runnning `php artisan config:cache` worked for me.

Comment: When you update JWT, the problem is solved with your answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -2):

solved using

```
composer update

composer install
```