# Issue with laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I am facing this issue when I use php artisan commmand it gives me this message

[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]   Call to undefined method Closure::__set_state()

Comment: can you clear cache using command "php artisan cache:clear " ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 on php artisan config:clear generated Closure::\_\_set\_state() error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31154313/laravel-5-on-php-artisan-configclear-generated-closure-set-state-error)

Comment: I did php artisan cache:clear nothing change same issue

Comment: it happened after installed UniSharp/laravel-filemanager , it was working fine but then it gives me this error