# Running any PHP Artisan/Composer commands return an error

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-artisan, php-deployer

I'm trying to Deploy my Laravel application to a staging server when I encountered this error

```
[ErrorException] require(/var/www/html/<app name>/releases/<version number>/vendor/composer/../../App/Helpers/DateHelper.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

At first I thought it was simply because Laravel recognize the path to DateHelper as App/Helpers/DateHelper.php instead of app/helpers/DateHelper.php, so I tried to change the pathname in composer.json's autoload from "App" to "app". After I changed it, I tried to clear the cache by running php artisan config:cache, then I got this error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/<app name>/releases/<version number>/vendor/composer/../../App/Helpers/DateHelper.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/<app name>/releases/<version number>/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 71
```

The same goes for when I was running any composer command (composer install, update, or dump-autoload). I tried searching for a config.php file, as suggested by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31154313/laravel-5-on-php-artisan-configclear-generated-closure-set-state-error), in my project's bootstrap/cache/ folder but the folder turns out to be empty.
What's worse is that running php artisan or any php artisan command would also result in the same PHP Fatal Error. Any ideas as to what is causing this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please share more details - why not use the same casing for all paths and files?

Comment: On a server paths are case sensitive. I would say: look at the Laravel naming conventions for paths, files and classnames.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late follow-up. Yes it turns out that there is another key called "files" in "autoload"  where I need to change the path from "App" to "app" and everything works like charm. I was panicking because I could not run any php artisan command and I thought the problems were deeper down the line.